# DataBase Not Updating In VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlcommand

I am running this code to add a row to my database but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim SqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GlacierDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
Dim CommandString1 As String = "INSERT INTO MemberDB VALUES ('1', 'JEET', 'ADDRESSX', 'MALE', '900001234', '10/04/2012', '20/12/2014')"

        Dim SqlCommand1 As New SqlCommand(CommandString1, SqlConnection1)

        SqlCommand1.Connection.Open()

        SqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But when i running insert into command in server explorer new query it working properly. any idea?

Comment: no exception. its running without any error.... but after i close the application... when i am checking row... there no new row...

and if i click the button second time as id is primary key i am getting a error that mean entry getting updated but after closing the application. data reverting back...

Comment: OK I GOT THAT:

when i running this program a another mdf file creating at debug folder and entry updating there and after i rerun that mdf replaced with default mdf so its rolling back, any solution on that? do i need to delete mdf file from solution explorer.

Comment: Ah - `LocalDb` - Haven't used that extensively I'm afraid...Is there some initialization (db creation) check on application start?

Comment: Don't you need to specify the column names after the MemberDB table, like INSERT INTO MemberDB (ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ...) VALUES ('1', 'JEET', ....) ?

Comment: you might also be passing the wrong types by putting something like a DATE in ticks - that converts it to text.  Also, without specifying the columns you might be setting them in the wrong order.

Comment: thanks for your answer guys... i have solved my problem by selecting do not copy option at GlacierDB.mdf property... :) thanks for ur all support.... :) And david in SQL we can all pass the values by INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2) order.... :)